# Why does changing background color prevent this css toggle button from working correctly

Tags: html, css

Tried modifying this css radio button: [link](https://codepen.io/magnificode/pen/ojYJJP/)

If I change the background of the body it works fine but if I wrap the code in a `div` and change the background of the `div` the transition stops working.  What is the explanation?  I assume it has to do with the background transition for `.btn` but I when I play around with it I can't get it to work. How would I fix this so it would work with any background?

Here is HTML

```
<input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" value="false" type="radio" checked>
<label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Yes</label>
<input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" value="true" type="radio">
<label for="toggle-off" class="btn">No</label>
```

and CSS (changed to regular css from link)

```
body, html {
  background: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.btn {
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 60px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
  border-right: 0;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
  left: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
  left: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  cursor: default;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `z-index: -1` set on `body` and `html`.  If you wrap your toggle button in a `div` element, and set the `div` element to have lower `z-index` value than `body` and `html`, then you'll be able to achieve what you are after.  Like so:

```css
body, html {
  background: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
div {
    background-color: tomato;
    z-index: -2;
}
.btn {
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 60px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
  border-right: 0;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
  left: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
  left: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  cursor: default;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" value="false" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn">Yes</label>
    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" value="true" type="radio">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The font color has also to match the background. `input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label { color: tomato; }`

Comment: How would this work with nested divs?  I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: @bigbucky, it depends how deep you are thinking of nesting? Also, please keep in mind the semantic markup as well.